# How to navigate huge code base ~1GB on windows

Tags: c

The code pertains to network switch's ROM and the total memory requirement for default, un-parsed code is around 1 GB. We use Cscope to browse the code in Linux, which is totally great, it doesn't takes time in building cross reference and very easy to use. I want to have the same experience on Windows.

Sadly no other similar question on SO answers my query. The code is mindbogglingly huge, and what surprises me is how Cscope manages to handle it so easily while no other tool on Windows does. I've tried Source Insight, Source Navigator, and many other tools but they take forever to build cross reference, ultimately I have to end their process.

Is there anything on earth which does on Windows, what Cscope does on Linux?

Answer (score 3):

I have not used `cscope` on windows, but you can try the downloads available on [this page](http://code.google.com/p/cscope-win32/)

Another possible way as given in `cscope` [support](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/) is using cscope (Linux package) under Cygwin.